# How to send notifications to Azure Resource Group owners?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation

I am looking for a way to notify Azure RG owners when their Resource Groups will be deleted automatically in 3,2,1 days.

I have an Automation Account implemented with a Runbook that cleans the Azure Sandbox - all RGs older than 2 weeks.
Now, instead of just delete the RG, would be nicer to also notify them :-)

Is there a way to have this done?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [Get-AzRoleAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azroleassignment?view=azps-5.9.0) command to get the RG owner object ID:

`Get-AzRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName 'owner'  | where {$_.Scope -eq '/subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourceGroups/<group name>' } | select objectId`

2. Use [Get-AzADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azaduser?view=azps-5.9.0) to query a user's email address to send notifications:

`Get-AzADUser -objectid <user object ID> | select mail`

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
Let me put it another way: 

I have an Automation Account with a Powershell Workbook that is scrambling in the Get-AzureRmLog for the older RGs and deletes them.
I also have tags with the respective RGs (e.g. TechnicalOwner: xyz@domain.com)

How can I combine the 2 situations above and have the owners notified that RG will be deleted...

Another RunBook, a LogicApp, or anything else?
How to implement email?

Comment: @DanielS I think querying tags will be much easier and faster than check logs.  So you can just check if there are tags you need exist on RGs,if yes, get the email and go to send emails. If not, then check logs. 
For sending emails, you can try logic App, exposing an HTTP trigger to allow your runbook trigger the email sending process. For details , you can refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-send-email?tabs=dotnet#create-the-logic-app

Comment: @DanielS，how's going? Has your issue got resolved?

Comment: nope, I still have to figure out what will be the architecture of this solution. I already have a working Runbook in place (to delete old RGs). Probably I will link it to a Logic App that will handle the email notifications. I am wondering if anyone else had to do this...probably yes...